# awk simple tab separation for 1 to nth column

Tags: awk, cat

I have a tab-delimited file that I want to print the first thee columns of.

I would prefer to keep my way of doing this as simple and reproducible as possible:

```
awk -F" " '{print $1,"\t" ,$2, "\t", $3}' old.bed > new.bed
```

But when I try further analysis on the new file I get an error saying that the file is of an unexpected format...

I check the contents of the file with:

```
cat -A new.bed | more

chr1     3000870     3000918$
chr1     3000870     3000918$
chr1     3000872     3000920$
chr1     3000872     3000920$
chr1     3000872     3000920$
```

It looks normal....

what is going wrong and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

The `$` are not in the file. It's the `-A` flag of `cat` that adds them in the display. Relevant parts from `man cat`:

> ```
>    -A, --show-all
>           equivalent to -vET
>
>    -E, --show-ends
>           display $ at end of each line
> ```

Simply drop the `-A` flag, the `$` won't be displayed anymore.

In addition, I'm not sure the `awk` command does 100% what you intended.
The output is not actually `col1 tab col2 tab col3`,
but `col1 space tab space col2 space tab space col3`.
It's because every `,` in the `print` command is replaced with a field separator, and on top of that, you're also adding tabs.
Here's a simple way to make the columns tab separated:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is tab delimited, you can use `cut` as a simple and reproducible method:

```
cut -f 1-3 old.bed
```

As for your `$` question, janos has that fully covered in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602347/3266847).